# Problem with generation of dynamic pages in Next.JS. Error 404 gets printed instead

Tags: reactjs, api, next.js

I'm trying to learn Next.JS and after learning about `getStaticPaths()` I wanted to use it in a 'real life example'. However, contrary to the examples made with [JSONPlaceholder](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/) it seems that I can't get it to work, and instead I get a 404 error with no messages whatsoever. So I wanted to ask what am I doing wrong:

- is it the code itself (there's an error I can't see)
- is it the approach itself?

`index.js`

```
import Link from 'next/dist/client/link';

const CHAMPIONS_URL =
  'https://raw.communitydragon.org/latest/plugins/rcp-be-lol-game-data/global/default/v1/champion-summary.json';

export async function getStaticProps() {
  const res = await fetch(CHAMPIONS_URL);
  const champions = await res.json();

  return {
    props: { champions },
  };
}

const Champions = ({ champions }) => {
  // console.log(champions);

  return (
    <ul>
      {champions.slice(1).map((champion) => (
        <li key={champion.id}>
          <Link href={`/champions/${champion.name}`}>{champion.name}</Link>
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
};

export default Champions;
```

`[id].js`

```
const CHAMPIONS_URL =
  'https://raw.communitydragon.org/latest/plugins/rcp-be-lol-game-data/global/default/v1/champion-summary.json';

function getChampion(champion) {
  return `https://raw.communitydragon.org/latest/plugins/rcp-be-lol-game-data/global/default/v1/champions/${champion}.json`;
}

export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const res = await fetch(CHAMPIONS_URL);
  const champions = await res.json();

  const paths = champions.map((champion) => ({ params: { id: champion.id.toString() } }));

  return { paths, fallback: false };
}

export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
  const res = await fetch(getChampion(params.id));
  const champion = await res.json();

  return { props: { champion } };
}

const Champion = ({ champion }) => {
  console.log(champion);

  return <div>Champion</div>;
};

export default Champion;
```

Comment: do you have any other dynamic page or slug route on /champions ?

Comment: No. But from my research today, I've noticed that my issue isn't really uncommon, and it's just a Next.JS limitation (here's a GitHub thread: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/11272?sort=top). I understand now why it doesn't work, but can't think of any good alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is fine. The 404 error you're seeing doesn't originate from Next.js itself, but from the external endpoint inside your `getChampion()` function in `./pages/champions/[id].js` (and make sure `[id].js` exists in a directory named `champions`).

Passing `champion.name` to `${champion}.json` will result in an error after interpolation since you're expecting to use `params.id`:
https://raw.communitydragon.org/latest/plugins/rcp-be-lol-game-data/global/default/v1/champions/Annie.json

But passing `champion.id` instead will work:
https://raw.communitydragon.org/latest/plugins/rcp-be-lol-game-data/global/default/v1/champions/1.json

So you really just need to change your `<Link>` component in `.pages/index.js` from...

```
{/* if you use `name` this will error */}
<Link href={`/champions/${champion.name}`}>{champion.name}</Link>
```

...to:

```
{/* but if you use `id` (since your page is named `[id].js`) this should work */}
<Link href={`/champions/${champion.id}`}>{champion.name}</Link>
```